# Javascript array length returning 0

Tags: javascript, arrays

When I am using console.log to print the array length , it returns 0 .
But in the console , if I write `txt.length` it returns the actual length (i.e 60 in my case) . For this reason I can't iterate through the txt array.

```
var txt;

function preload() {
  txt = loadStrings("DataProcess/outData.txt");
  console.log(txt);
  console.log(txt.length);
}
```

Comment: Can we see what happens in `loadStrings` function? As you're passing a path to a file to that function, it badly seems, that there's some asyncronous action taken in the function.

Comment: What is `loadStrings()` here?

Comment: it is the p5.js loadStrings function . https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadStrings

Comment: @Zarif Visit this link [p5 load string](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/p5-js-loadstrings-function/) for string array you need use callback.

callback: This is a function which is called after the function is successfully executed. The first argument for this function is the strings array.

Comment: Yep, "_This method is asynchronous, meaning it may not finish before the next line in your sketch is executed_".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the length in the callback. from the docs the function accepts 3 arguments

`loadStrings(filename, [callback], [errorCallback])`

meaning you should do something like this:

```
var txt;

function preload() {
  loadStrings("DataProcess/outData.txt", (res) => {
    txt = res
    console.log(txt.length);
  })

}
```